# Can not set set image for custom button

Tags: ios, swift, button, customization

I'm going to implement a check box like this: [image]
by

```
class CheckBox: UIButton {
let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked")
let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked")
var checked : Bool = false{
    didSet{
        if checked == false{
            self.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
        }else {
            self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}
override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    checked = false
}
func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton){
    if (sender == self){
        checked = !checked
    }
}
```

}

but everything I got is: [image]

Could you explain what happened?

Comment: where you created the Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried your code it's works fine i only changed this part **self.addTarget...** to:

```
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CheckBox.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

and when you create the button change it class to: **CheckBox**

Answer (score -1):

Call `self.setNeedsLayout()` at the end of your `didSet` statement.
If you change any of subviews you need to ask it to update it's layout and children. Let me know if that helped.